# Difference between allocating memory and allocating memory for an array

Tags: c, memory-management

Is there a meaningful difference between `kmalloc` and `kmalloc_array`?

I was under the impression that memory was memory, but as it is described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/mm.html#idp7497952) there appears to be some difference.

> kmalloc — allocate memory
>
> kmalloc_array — allocate memory for an array.

Are they just two different ways to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I have not looked into these functions at all, but I would not be surprised of `kmalloc_array` places importance on the alignment of the buffer it returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the kernel-source (slab.h)

```
/**
* kmalloc_array - allocate memory for an array.
* @n: number of elements.
* @size: element size.
* @flags: the type of memory to allocate (see kmalloc).
*/
static inline void *kmalloc_array(size_t n, size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
      if (size != 0 && n > SIZE_MAX / size)
             return NULL;
      return __kmalloc(n * size, flags);
}
```

I wonder who needed that ;))

Comment: you can modify and adjust any functionality  as per your convenience :) That is luxury of using Linux kernel.